# “no symbol table is loaded” with cross tool chain gdb

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have observed kernel panic. To identify at which line kernel panic observed, I have followed last method (Using GDB to find the location where your kernel panicked or oopsed.) in the [link.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks)

I have used arm cross tool chain gdb, as the target is ARM board. But it is giving `"No symbol table is loaded.  Use the file command."` error.  I tried to load symbol table using `"file System.map"` , but it is giving `"System.map: not in executable format: File format not recognized"` error.

Can you help to address this symbol table issue. The host PC is running with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You may need to point the kernel binary (vmlinuz). And make sure that the kernel binary includes debugging symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Debug symbols included in kernel binary by enabling CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO in kernel config. Now it is not giving any error.